# Where is the maven-assembly-plugin debug log?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I got an error when trying to compile my project. It seems there is something wrong with the maven assembly plugin configuration.

```
07:30:58:298 [ERROR] org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.2.0:single (make-assembly) on project assembly-main: Assembly is incorrectly configured: dist: Assembly is incorrectly configured: dist: 
07:30:58:298 [ERROR] org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Assembly: dist is not configured correctly: One or more filters had unmatched criteria. Check debug log for more information.
```

To `Check debug log for more information.`,  I ran the same maven command with the `-X` option, but got nothing more:

```
07:30:58:298 [ERROR] org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.2.0:single (make-assembly) on project assembly-main: Assembly is incorrectly configured: dist
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Assembly is incorrectly configured: dist
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute (AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:546)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.assembly.mojos.SingleAssemblyMojo.execute (SingleAssemblyMojo.java:61)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
07:30:58:300 [ERROR] org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - 
07:30:58:300 [ERROR] org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - 
07:30:58:300 [ERROR] org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
07:30:58:300 [ERROR] org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Where are these "debug logs"? Or how can I pinpoint which filters are misconfigured?

Comment: As far as I know, Maven spits out the whole information in the console unless a specifi plugin writes to additional files and I don't think the assembly plugin does. Can you share a minimal reproducible example of this? Try to copy your project's pom and delete from it until you have a simple example that exhibits the error.

Comment: It looks like you are calling maven-assembly-plugin goal instead via the life cycle..second a pom file would be helpful...

Comment: I debugged it by commenting out sections. It seems I was adding a DependencySet witch only included a dependency that is no longer in the project.